# How to make the Visual Studio 2015 text templating security warning go away?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, code-generation, t4

This problem is making me mad.

We have a set of projects that rely on T4 templates to generate code for a bunch of DSLs.

Every time I try to transform one of these T4 templates in **Visual Studio 2015** I get this window, the security warning:

[image: Visual Studio 2015 text templating security warning]

I have set the "Do not show this message again".

I have set the VS option "Text Templating | Show Security Message" to false.

Every time I restart Visual Studio 2015 and transform the first template the message pops up again.

This does not happen in Visual Studio 2013.

Some hints that may have something to do with this:

- The actual text template that is called is published by a VS extension that is installed in the admin extensions directory ($ProgramFiles$\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions).
- We are using our own custom code generator (that derives from TemplatedCodeGenerator).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution to this one a little by chance.

The problem was that the assembly containing the custom code generator was referencing Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.VSHost.12.0 instead of version 14.0 as for Visual Studio 2015.

Oddly enough the transformation did not complain about the problem with the reference but completely ignored the VS option to stop showing the security dialog (may be because it was reading it from the wrong place?).

After correcting the reference, the problem never happened again.